# Python shortening simple if statement

Tags: python, if-statement

is it possible to make if statement shorter in this fragment of program?

```
for number in range(100):
    if (number % 4 == 0 and number % 3 == 0 and number % 2 == 0):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't want to do the math to combine them:

```
for number in range(100):
    if all(number % n == 0 for n in (2, 3, 4)):
```

Comment: Thank you, thats what i was looking for.

Comment: @Matthew You realize that this is *much* slower than simply finding the lcm once, at the start, then using that *single* number for all of the tests, right?  And if you're checking against, say, 10 different numbers, this approach will be 10 times slower than the lcm solution, which is tailor-made for this application.  This *does* answer your question, but it's much slower than it needs to be.

Answer (score 5):

Just use: `if number % 12 == 0:`

This is because 12 is the least common multiple of 4, 3, and 2.

**On Edit:**

Here is some code to compute the least common multiple of a list (or other iterable) of integers:

```
from math import gcd

def pair_lcm(a,b):
    return a*b//gcd(a,b)

def lcm(nums):
    """computes the lcm of iterable nums"""
    m = 1
    for num in nums:
        m = pair_lcm(m,num)
    return m
```

For example,

```
>>> lcm(range(1,11))
2520
```

Comment: yeah but  i need to find the smallest number divided by numbers for example in range from 1 to 10

Comment: @Matthew You asked how to simplify the `if` statement, not how to simplify the loop (whose purpose wasn't given in the question itself).

Comment: @Matthew You need to stick to the question you posted, not a followup question that you haven't posted yet.  In any case, if you want numbers to be multiples of all the numbers from 1 to 10, take their lcm and use that for the second argument to `%`.